# define var today and yesterday

Tags: php, date

I have

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
```

and I like to define also $yesterday

I tried to do

```
$yesterday=($today-1)
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try with:

```
$yesterday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('yesterday'));
```

Comment: Why was my answer downvoted ?

Comment: Im still wondering why its getting up- and downvoted all the time. Kinda funny to watch.

Comment: Probably because while the answer is correct, it answers an obviously duplicate, obviously help-vampiric, obviously something-you-shouldn't-answer question. The community expects a 34k user to vote to close the question, instead of answering it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
date("F j, Y", time() - 60 * 60 * 24);
```

Comment: You assume a day is 86400 seconds long.

Comment: @Maerlyn I guess it depends on which planet you are from.  On mine a day is 86,400 seconds long

Comment: Every day? Surely not, just think about when you switch to/from DST.

Comment: @Steve - Not all Australian states have daylight savings, but a blanket statement that `a day is 86,400 seconds long` doesn't hold for all parts of your own country, let alone the world

Comment: All true...I concede :o)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php):

```
$date = new DateTime('');
$date->modify('-1 day');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
```